# Why HttpServletRequest is used to send a response to the browser?

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm developing a web application by using Spring MVC and I came out with a question.
In my application, if I want to send attributes to a JSP file, I do something like:

```
    @RequestMapping("submitRestrictionPolicy")
    public String submitRestrictionPolicy(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        // Get parameters from form submit
        String state = req.getParameter("checkBox");

        // Set attributes to be sent to .jsp page
        req.setAttribute("state", state);

        return "restrictionPolicy";
    }
```

And this works normally, I can access the attribute "state" in JSP file and reflect it in browser.

Now I'm wondering why we use HttpServletRequest instead of HttpServletResponse because from my understanding we are sending a response of a request from browser. Shouldn't we use HttpServletResponse for it? I know the answer is no, since there's no "setAttribute" method in HttpServletResponse.

And if it's correct to send responses for a browser request by using HttpServletRequest, what is the importance of HttpServletResponse?

Answer (score 0):

Lets see how things work...

The client sends a request (HttpServletRequest) to the webserver. This request may pass from several layers (depending on your application) until it is no more necessary(HttpServletResponse is send back from the server to the client).

In these layers you can modify this HttpServletRequest object and add information(attributes) to it. Then as you generate the HttpServletResponse based on the HttpServletRequest, you can make use of that extra information propagated from the previous layers(this is usually done in the view layer).

Now something more general about how `HttpServlet`s works might answer your last question. When an http put/get/post/.... request is made on the web container (that servlets run ), this request is wrapped in an Object of type HttpServletRequest(This is how the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) is) and contains the information from your client. When the response is created, it is wrapped in a HttpServletResponse Object that contains the response data of the web container (again based on the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html)).

Comment: When you say: "Then as you generate the HttpServletResponse based on the HttpServletRequest". That is my point, I am generating the response to web browser by adding attributes in HttpServeltResquet object.. and, it works! By your logic (and mine logic also) I should use HttpServletResponse, right?

Comment: you are using attributes and parameters from the HttpServeltResquet to generate the HttpServletResponse

Comment: but when the HttpServletResponse is generate? I don't set any attributes or parameters on it

Comment: yes you do, in the jsp there are lines such as `<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` or anything you output to the jsp, is being tranformed to HttpServletResponse by the framework

Comment: @MaVRoSCy - It's the only question on SO about that subject. Do you mind to improve your answer with some detailed steps? It would be really helpfull.